# Audio Problems with Playstation 1 on Vizio TV

Tags: technical-issues, ps1

I recently pulled out my old PlayStation and hooked it up to my LCD Vizio TV. When i started playing Croc: Legend of the Gobbos the audio worked fine on my dolby surround but later on it started glitching on and off and eventually barely worked at all. I switched the sound to stereo which worked for a little bit and then stopped. I tried Mono also with the same results. I then started up Duke Nukem: Total Meltdown and the audio rarely played on any mode (Stereo A, Stereo B, Dolby Surround). I then tried Colony Wars with the audio still glitching on every mode. If someone could tell me how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's an old playstation, sounds like something in the sound card is starting to die, it might not be fixable =[

Comment: Could be that the cable is broken. Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Thank you for giving me this information. Sadly i dont have another Cable and, from the outside, it doesnt seem that the current one is broken. If the sound card is broken then i guess i might be out of luck. Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you using SCART or Bananas?

Comment: I am using Bananas.

Comment: On a side note, a PlayStation 3 can play most PS1 discs.  A few have issues, though (second and third Spyro games lose sound in cutscenes for instance).  PS2 games, on the other hand, only work with early PS3 models.

Comment: And of course i have a Wii U and Xbox 360 and no PS3

Comment: hey guys. I'd like to thank you guys who helped me get closer to a solution. It turned out that the AV cord wasnt fully lodged into the ps1. I played around in Namco Museum for 15 minutes and everything went smooth. Thanks!